# LG DA-3630 switchmode power supply repair - chirpy sound

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, mains, repair, debugging

I attempted a repair of the switchmode PSU of the DVD player in the title, and while I made promising progress, there is something still missing.

#### Initial problem:

- when plugged in, nothing happened - no LEDs come on
- Inside chassis:

  - main high voltage cap - 220u 450V - bulged (C906)
  - DH0165 IC devastated: 1 pin burnt, detached from casing, burn marks on PCB (pin 8, IC902)
  - two large ceramic resistors show the signs of having been exposed to high thermals (R930, R931 glue material went from yellowish to brown, peeled off on one of them)
- no information available on what caused the problem

I guessed that the poor DH0165 either died a horrible death because the primary cap didn't do the filtering properly anymore, or both of them died due to a voltage surge of some kind.

#### Fix attempt:

- Swapped DH0165 IC
- swapped primary cap

  - measured capacitance of old one: my meter only measures up to 200u, and it seems to be above that

Testing

- Applied mains voltage for 1s to see what happens
- red LED comes on on front panel
- DVD motor starts spinning
- typical "secondary caps almost completely failed in SMPS" sound: high pitched, periodically clicking, chirpy voice

#### Conclusion so far

- might still be repairable
- PSU seems to still be wrong, though no visible damage anywhere

#### Questions

- What could be the cause if the failure?
- How to proceed with investigation?

  - I am afraid to have mains applied for long enough to make measurements on the board due to the death cry the PSU gives out...
  - As this is an SMPS, I doubt the old "put a small wattage bulb in series in the mains" trick would do good here: the PSU would even actually have to work harder, thus I feel it would just accelerate the demise of the whole thing.
  - I tested the PSU all connected and inside the closed chassis at first, with an extinguisher ready (if it blows up, rather do that in a sort of closed space there...)
  - Now that it seems not to blow up immediately, should I test it outside of the chassis? Maybe the chirping sound is due to a different fault in another panel overloading the PSU?
  - Would it be worth to whip out my trusty old CRT oscilloscope to see what is going on in the secondary side?
- Should I blindly replace all secondary caps before even thinking, given that the mains cap bulged, and try after that?

*(Disclaimer: This question involves **deadly voltages**, anyone finding this and trying to follow what I did or any of the answers recommend: please consider your limits when tampering with such, **there is a high risk of electrocution and fire!** I'm experienced to build and work with equipment having high voltages, including mains and even higher inside, and have proper, though DIY quality tools to carry this through.)*

#### Information

**Schematic of SMPS module**
[image: Schematic of SMPS module]

**DH0165 block diagram**
[image]

Comment: You cannot be sure that the initial fault didn't start in the main circuit (the DVD player itself) rather than the power supply and then caused the power supply to fail too.

Comment: Try replacing C923. Measuring capacitors using the capacitance range on a multimeter won’t detect ESR problems.

Comment: @Andyaka agreed - as history is unknown, this might even be the case. However, without a working PSU, this can not be properly debugged...

Comment: Are you testing the power supply independent of the DVD?

Comment: @Kartman you're right, ESR can mess up the whole thing - I'll swap C923 to see if something changes.

Comment: @Andyaka didn't do that yet - wanted to check with people who know better before testing the board out of the chassis (the main amplifier/CPU board connects using pins/sockets directly, no way to just unplug cables...) BTW, would it not fry itself without load on the secondary side of the standby SMPS?

Comment: Consider 5% dummy loads for stability and for primary side measurement  use scope ground to Earth gnd with 2 in differential mode .